# C# open multiple images to array

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm new to C# and I'm trying to open multiple images to an array to later manipulate their pixels, this is my code so far:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Image Files(*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.bmp)|*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.bmp";
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Bitmap[] images = new Bitmap(openFileDialog1.FileNames);
            MessageBox.Show(images.Length+" images loaded","",MessageBoxButtons.OK);

        }
    }
```

I'm getting problems with this line

```
Bitmap[] images = new Bitmap(openFileDialog1.FileNames);
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use:

```
 images = openFileDialog1.FileNames.Select(fn=>new Bitmap(fn)).ToArray();
```

Because openFileDialog1.FileNames is array of strings and Bitmap constructor expects single image file name

Answer (score 3):

```
Bitmap[] images = new Bitmap(openFileDialog1.FileNames);

Bitmap[] images // Is an array of Bitmap

new Bitmap(openFileDialog1.FileNames); // Returns a single (new) Bitmap
```

I suggest to use a List. And when you are new to C# it is much easier to use foreach than LinQ as Pavel Kymets suggested.

```
List<Bitmap> images = new List<Bitmap>();
foreach(string file in openFileDialog1.FileNames) {
    images.Add(new Bitmap(file));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, if you aren't ready for lambdas, something like

```
openFileDialog1.Filter = "Image Files(*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.bmp)|*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.bmp";       
List<BitMap> images = new List<BitMaps>()
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
  foreach(string fileName in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
  {
     images.Add(new Bitmap(fileName));
  }
} 
MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0} images loaded",images.Count),"",MessageBoxButtons.OK);
```